# Want to display bad data information

Tags: active-directory, powershell-2.0

My list is of employee numbers, but if some numbers on my list is not in Active Directory, in the results those IDs get bypassed so I do not know that was an incorrect number. Can I get the bad IDs to also show on my list?

```psh
Get-Content c:\temp\disable.txt | ForEach-Object {
  Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(samaccountname=$_)" |
    Select-Object -Property samaccountname,surname,givenname,enabled
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an object yourself if the query doesn't produce a result:

```
Get-Content c:\temp\disable.txt | ForEach-Object {
  $user = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(samaccountname=$_)" |
    Select-Object -Property samaccountname,surname,givenname,enabled
  if ($user) {
    $user
  } else {
    New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
      samaccountname = $_
      surname        = ''
      givenname      = ''
      enabled        = $null
    }
  }
}
```